# What would cause cURL to succeed on HTTPS, but fail on HTTP?

Tags: php, apache, curl, connection-timeout

On one old shared server there is this test cURL script. It returns from a straightforward GET request without problems for **https**://www.bing.com, but times out or returns partial content for **http**://www.bing.com and times out. Increasing the timeout does not help.

The above misbehavior can be reproduced with other URLs from google.com, example.com and yahoo.com.

Tech support is <strike>useless</strike> not helpful. Again, it's an old shared server so I can't go in and troubleshoot it with any granularity. What could cause this unexpected behavior?

```
<?php
    // FAILS - timeout or partial content AND timeout
    $URL="http://www.bing.com";

    // SUCCEEDS
    //$URL="https://www.bing.com";

    if (isset($_GET["site"])) { $URL = $_GET["site"]; }
    $ch = curl_init();
    echo "URL = $URL <br>\n";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    echo "<hr><br>\n";
    echo 'Errors: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' ' . curl_error($ch) . '<br><br>';
    echo "<hr><br>\n";
    curl_close ($ch);
    print "result - $result";
    echo "<hr><br>\n";
?>
```

**Sample outputs:**

> Errors: 28 Operation timed out after 20000 milliseconds with 0 bytes
>   received

or

> Errors: 28 Operation timed out after 19811 milliseconds with 7709 out
>   of 92270 bytes received

Note, this script succeeds on other servers. I'm trying to narrow down points of failure.

Server: Apache, PHP 5.3, FastCGI

Comment: Sounds like a routing or proxying problem from that specific server. This is definitely one for tech support who have more access to the server and can diagnose its network. If they're really that useless you should threaten to take your business elsewhere, and actually do if they don't help.

Comment: Maybe the site is HTTPs only? Add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` (Assuming this isn't *actually* failing on http://www.bing.com)

Comment: @charmeleon I thought that too, but it resolves with the `http` protocol with no redirects. Additionally OP mentioned it works on other servers.

Comment: @Drakes Windows or Linux server?

Comment: @fyrye Linux (last build was 2013).

Comment: @Roadmaster I have 6 months until this shared plan ends. I'm already migrating to a new server. I just got off the phone with tech support guy #5 who says increase the timeout... more that 240 seconds. Can you believe that? I need some suggestions to help them do their job.

Comment: Just for testing try `$test = file_get_contents('http://www.bing.com'); var_dump($test);` It should test the same networking protocols if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled

Comment: @fyrye It succeeded with near-zero latency